# How can I use Power Query or VBA to automate updating a master file from separate desktops in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have a master file that needs to be updated every morning with other excel files which are being updated by 5 different individual files.
The individiual files would be on their desktop. They currently update the master file every morning seperately, so the master file wont crash. I think it has around 1000+ rows with many many columns.

The master file is on a teams folder.

I have tried power query, but I dont know how to update from different desktops? Or should I take the VBA Route?

Comment: Instead of having each user update the same master file, have each user just copy their own file to the teams folder every morning, either manually or with VBA, doesn't matter. Then use power query to read from those copies on the teams folder.